# How do I make my JQuery work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi :) I've been playing around with javascript and now want to check out JQuery. I still need to learn a lot, so please be nice :) I took a code from the web and now I am trying to get it to work. The Jsfiddle works, it just doesn't want to work on my server. Here is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<html lang="en"> 

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/play/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function getNum(element, attrPrefix) {
    //set prefix, get number
    var prefix = attrPrefix;
    var num = element.attr("id").substring((prefix.length));
    return num;
}

$(":checkbox").change(function() {
    var num = getNum($(this), "checkbox_");
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#color_" + num).val($(this).val());
    } else {
        $("#color_" + num).val("");
    }
});

</script>

</head>

<body>

<p>Input boxes are populated with value of checkbox when checkbox is checked.</p>

<p><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_01" name="checkbox" value="red was checked" />red 01<br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_02" name="checkbox_02" value="green was checked" />green 02<br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_03" name="checkbox_03" value="blue was checked" />blue 03</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>color 01<input type="text" id="color_01" name="color_01" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>color 02<input type="text" id="color_02" name="color_02" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>color 03<input type="text" id="color_03" name="color_03" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>


<body>
</html>
```

No matter what I change the src to, it just doesn't want to make the JQuery thingy work. I copied the min file directly into my wamp prjtect directory called play. I used :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/play/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Please, let me know what I can do to make this work ! Thanks in advance :) Note : I am a web developer beginner ;)

Comment: As RGS have answered, you'll need to add the document ready wrapper and make sure you're only including the jQuery library **once**. Preferably using an [CDN](http://jquery.com/download/#using-jquery-with-a-cdn).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your code inside DOM ready handler. Then remove any one jquery reference file or else use jquery CDN library.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"/>
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function getNum(element, attrPrefix) {
    //set prefix, get number
    var prefix = attrPrefix;
    var num = element.attr("id").substring((prefix.length));
    return num;
}
$(":checkbox").change(function() {
    var num = getNum($(this), "checkbox_");
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#color_" + num).val($(this).val());
    } else {
        $("#color_" + num).val("");
    }
});
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/9fLXL/

Answer (score 0):

Please try wrapping your js/jquery code in

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //your code here
});
```

or

```
$(function() {
    //your code here
});
```